# Grunt crashing after warning "unexpected end of input" on expressServer task - OS X Yosemite, Ember App Kit

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, ember-cli, ember-app-kit

I was away from our Rails + Ember project, and didn't realize that my local environment had totally broken with upgrade to OS X Yosemite. A number of steps were remedied (e.g. fixing /usr/local/ permissions for homebrew or getting an earlier version of Phantomjs) - but now I've been stuck with Grunt for a few days and need help.

**Stack:**

Ember app kit on the front-end, rails on the backend.

**Problem:**

running `grunt server`, I get a warning as such:

```
...
Done, without errors.

Running "expressServer:debug" (expressServer) task
Warning: Unexpected end of input Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Running it with `--verbose` flag doesn't shed any light at all, exactly the same error.

Using `--force` flag, it appears to continue - but doesn't actually serve the app.

**Relevant task from `Gruntfile.js`**:

Actually, default that [came from EAK](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L108-L121):

```
grunt.registerTask('server', "Run your server in development mode, auto-rebuilding when files change.", function(proxyMethod) {
  var expressServerTask = 'expressServer:debug';
  if (proxyMethod) {
    expressServerTask += ':' + proxyMethod;
  }

  grunt.task.run(['clean:debug',
                  'build:debug',
                  expressServerTask,
                  'watch'
                  ]);
});
```

Now I'm totally at loss how to debug it further. Excessive googling didn't help me, there are no logs to look at, and the error message isn't guiding me :-(

Any ideas how I could make grunt server actually serve my app?

Comment: did you try the debug flag? I don't *think* verbose gives you debug

Comment: Thanks for the hint! That adds a line "[D] Task source: tasks/express-server.js" before failing, but otherwise just the same.

Comment: I had a ton of problems with ruby after upgrading to Yeosemite - had to use at least 2.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is stating that a curly brace is not closed. I would assume that a bower install has been interrupted or failed. Try clearing the bower cache (bower cache clean) then bower update.